# Modal Popup controls of Ajax in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

In asp.net, i am trying to popup the modal popup control when user select on button which is in gridview. But when i am running that page it is giving error like:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for     Controls and Behaviors.  Parameter name: element
```

My code is :

```
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="grdReport" PopupControlID ="pnlPoup"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The TargetControl property is set to "gridview", can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this error it was due a space character in the ID of the ModalPopupExtender's parent control. (Spaces are not legal in Control.ID).

Other unusual characters in control IDs may also trigger this error: see [ASP.NET AJAX Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470207/asp-net-ajax-problem)